# Best practice implementing security on an Extjs / Java application

Tags: java, spring, security, extjs

So I had an ExtJs / Java application deployed on a private server and network and didn't need to implement security, but now I had been requested to deploy that application on the cloud, choose  OpenShift (Red Hat Cloud) so far so good... but I've been wondering how to implement security ...
I used to work with spring security core (with Grails) but my application database is CouchDB (actually using CloudAnt service) and it doesn't seems to be nor easy or natural to connect it...

What would you recommend ?

right now I have let's say `http:re-hat-something-else/myapp/mybussinesinterface.html` which I don't want to show unless you are logged, so lets say I already have `mylogin.html` and lets say I already have a business method that authenticates users, would it be right to store in localstorage a token that would tell me if the user went through the log in page to validate if someone is trying to open directly `http:re-hat-something-else/myapp/mybussinesinterface.html`

Of course I would also have to add extra security to all my back -end methods to validate nobody is trying to execute them directly ...

Any ideas ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it's the server's job to protect its content from unauthorized users. If the JavaScript is served up to an unauthorized client, all bets are off.  Same goes for the Java REST API: if it is exposed to unauthorized clients, all bets are off.  Clearly the server needs to protect both the Java and the JavaScript resources.

You're running your application inside of some sort of container (Tomcat, JBoss, etc). The questions you're asking are best answered by implementing some sort of security at the container level. For example, if you use [shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) with JBoss, it's as simple as implementing a servlet filter that would deny access to your application for unauthorized users. I'm sure you can do something similar with Tomcat.

Oh, and make sure you know the difference between "authorize" and "authenticate". Chances are, no one else really understands it and you'll need to explain it to them.  (If they do understand the difference, count yourself lucky.)